# Package name breaks JNI classpath?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm working on a JNI application. It is a C program that calls some Java methods.

I wrote it following some internet examples.

First I created a simple example in Eclipse Indigo (it created the Java files in a "default package"). Then I used something like this in the C code:

```
options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/home/elias/workspace/Funciones/bin";
```

All worked fine but then I re-made the Java proyect to have the Java code in a package called "Funciones", so I modified to:

```
options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/home/elias/workspace/Funciones/bin/Funciones";
```

But now I doesn't work... I supposed it is something I have wrong in the classpath.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Your classpath shouldn't point *inside* the packages, just to a directory holding them. Your original version should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid the original doesn't work... I have this: funciones  = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Funciones"); Maybe the problem is here? Thanks.

Comment: If `Funciones` is a package, then it's obviously not the class name you're looking for. Not sure what the layout of your code is, but you should do something like `(*env)->FindClass(env, "Funciones/Funciones");`

Comment: @millimoose, perhaps you would care to turn this comment into an answer, so if things work out it can be accepted and the question won't remain technically unanswered forever.

Comment: Thanks  millimoose that made the trick!!! Now can I also load classes from a *.jar file?  Something like: options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/path/to/my/jar/myjar.jar"; ?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1274605 Exactly. Just like you point the class path at a filesystem directory that holds a bunch of packages, you can point it at a `.jar` file that holds a bunch of packages.

Comment: @MvG I usually do that once it turns out my educated guess was in fact correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help millimoose. Please let me bother you with this other question, Can a Java function return to a plain C (not C/C++) jni program somethig like ArrayList list; or ArrayList<String> list; ? or some other kind of container?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1274605 Don't glom unrelated questions into comments, post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the class path to point at the directory (or directories, or `jar` files) holding the top-level packages you're using, not *inside* the packages. So if your code is laid out like this:

```
~/Funciones/bin/
|
>----Funciones
|    |
|    >----Funciones.class – this is the class Funciones.Funciones
|
>----some other package
|
:
```

you need to add `~/Funciones/bin` to your classpath. To find the class, you need to use its [fully qualified name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) – the class name prefixed with the package name:

```
Class clsFunciones = Class.forName("Funciones.Funciones");
```

or, in JNI, the [class descriptor](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/types.html#65751):

```
jclass clsFunciones = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Funciones/Funciones");
```